# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.DefaultFormats While running flink job

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am using flink-1.4.2 with scala. While running my code with flink. I am getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[]) method from the class org.example.WindowExample: org/json4s/DefaultFormats$
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/DefaultFormats$
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the *json4s* dependency to your *pom.xml*, or if already exists, set its scope to *compile*.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I need to add in scope to compile

Comment: Remember json dependaciyes in pom.xml should be compatible with spark json lib for example for spark 3.3.x this version works:
 "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.6.6",